# Icons behaving weirdly

Tags: icons, ico

I made an application with Visual Studio 2019. I already set an icon for it, but then I wanted to change it. When I changed the icon, in some folders where I had the program saved with the old icon, the displayed icon didn't change when in replaced the file. The program only contains one icon file. I even tried redoing the program by deleting the vs project and copying my code. After that didn't work, I tried changing the icon back but now in every folder that once contained the file while it had the newer icon, the file wouldn't change back. Renaming the file doesn't work either. I have never seen this before. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

So, it went away by itself. If you ever have this problem, it will probably go away on its own. Don't exactly know how long it takes, restart is not enough. It took only one day in my case.

EDIT:
It was because of Windows icon caching.
Restarting the pc helps.